# Mongoose doesn't execute save and doesn't display error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hi i have the following code:

```
export function createProduct(req, res) {
    console.log("Execution")
    const product = new Product({ ...req.body })
    product.save(function (err, product) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error")
            const errorResponse = {}
            for (let key in err.errors) {
                //ValidationError handler
                if (err.errors[key].properties) {
                    errorResponse[key] = err.errors[key].properties.message
                }
                //CastError handler
                else {
                    errorResponse[key] = err.errors[key].toString().split(":")[1]
                }
            }
            return res.status(400).send({ ...errorResponse })
        }
        console.log("created")
        return res.send({ product })
    })
}
```

There is no error on express side, console.log("Execution") is working and display this message correctly. I tested this by using Postman, when i send some data, response never come and on Postman there is error: "Error: socket hang up".

I've made console.log for req.body, and this is my output:

```
{
  name: 'Apple Iphone 11 Pro 64GB Space Gray',
  category: 'smartphone',
  price: 4699,
  inMagazine: { blocked: 0, inStock: 40 },
  shortDescription: 'Odkryj wszystkie zalety iPhone 11 Pro 512 GB Silver. Smartfona, który zawstydza podkręconą wydajnością. Posiada bowiem najszybszy w historii procesor A13 Bionic oraz baterię, która pozwala na wiele. Weź iPhone 11 Pro do ręki i rób zdjęcia, których nie powstydziłby się nawet profesjonalista. Teraz masz do tego odpowiednie narzędzie – nowy iPhone 11 Pro posiada potrójny aparat główny, działający w oparciu o uczenie maszynowe. Efekty swojej fotograficznej przygody wraz z najmniejszymi detalami możesz ocenić z kolei na olśniewającym ekranie Super Retina XDR.',
  images: [ { order: 1, src: '' } ]
}
```

Right after that, I found that I would check why it hangs, I had no error in the nodejs console. So I added two console.log to the code:

```
console.log("error")
```

```
console.log("created")
```

But both doesn't execute. So i made some code refactor and this works the same like above:

```
export async function createProduct(req, res) {
    try {
        const product = await Product.create({ ...req.body })
        console.log("created")
        return res.send({ product })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error")
        const errorResponse = {}
        for (let key in err.errors) {
            //ValidationError handler
            if (err.errors[key].properties) {
                errorResponse[key] = err.errors[key].properties.message
            }
            //CastError handler
            else {
                errorResponse[key] = err.errors[key].toString().split(":")[1]
            }
        }
        return res.status(400).send({ ...errorResponse })
    } 
}
```

I don't know what the cause of this problem could be.
This is link to whole project: https://github.com/codemasternode/DietShopping

Comment: Show what does you passed in `{ ...req.body }` please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know that if you are saving the products like this all the keywords in the `req.body` should be the same as in the `Product` schema.
This should work:

```
exports.createProduct = async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const product = new Product(req.body).save();
        return res.json(product);
    }catch(err){
        const errorResponse = {}
            for (let key in err.errors) {
                if (err.errors[key].properties) {
                    errorResponse[key] = err.errors[key].properties.message
                }
                else {
                    errorResponse[key] = err.errors[key].toString().split(":")[1]
                }
            }
            return res.status(400).send({ ...errorResponse })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the return(s) in front of the res. function calls

Like this:

```
export async function createProduct(req, res) {
try {
    const product = await Product.create({ ...req.body })
    console.log("created")
    res.send({ product })
} catch (err) {
    console.log("error")
    const errorResponse = {}
    for (let key in err.errors) {
        //ValidationError handler
        if (err.errors[key].properties) {
            errorResponse[key] = err.errors[key].properties.message
        }
        //CastError handler
        else {
            errorResponse[key] = err.errors[key].toString().split(":")[1]
        }
    }
    res.status(400).send({ ...errorResponse })
}
```

Comment: This is link to whole repo: https://github.com/codemasternode/DietShopping

Answer (score 0):

I've had an pre save in "products" model that doesn't let me go through. I was copying and pasting from other model and forget to remove unecesarry code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you get rid of that callbacks and use clean async-await. By using this codes will be shorter too. And I think this will work. Try this.

```js
export async function createProduct(req, res) {
    try{
        console.log("Execution")
        const product = new Product({...req.body})
        let result = await product.save()
        console.log("created",result)
        return res.send({ product })
    }catch(err){
        const errorResponse = {}
            for (let key in err.errors) {
                if (err.errors[key].properties) {
                    errorResponse[key] = err.errors[key].properties.message
                }
                else {
                    errorResponse[key] = err.errors[key].toString().split(":")[1]
                }
            }
            return res.status(400).send({ ...errorResponse })
    }
}
```